# Undefined Index Error PHP $_POST

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, xampp

I'm not that new to HTML but I **am** still very new to PHP.  Right now I've created a MySQL Database using XAMPP and within that I can see all my tables (as expected).  I've got a PHP script that displays all the information in one of my tables.  The table has `NULL` values in it because the user is supposed to input information into it and then click a button that says `Update` and it's supposed to update my database and table with said values.  (If any of the above confused you, hopefully what's written after the scripts will clarify it).  Here are my scripts:

**NOTE: the `dbconnect.php` script simply contains my connection to my database**

#### index.php

```
<?php
require_once('dbconnect.php');
$query = "SELECT * FROM event_list";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
?>

<table width="auto" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="results.php">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table width="auto" border="1" cellspacing="1"     cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center"><strong>Event ID</strong></td>
                        <td align="center"><strong>Title</strong></td>
                        <td align="center"><strong>Topic</strong></td>
                        <td align="center"><strong>Description</strong></td>
                        <td align="center"><strong>Event Date</strong></td>
                        <td align="center"><strong>Speaker</strong></td>
                        <td align="center"><strong>Building</strong></td>
                        <td align="center"><strong>Room</strong></td>
                    </tr>

                    <?php                    
                        while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    ?>

                    <tr>
                        <?php
                            $id[]=$rows['event_id'];
                        ?>
                        <td align="center">
                            <?php echo $rows['event_id'];?>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <input name="title[]" type="text" id="title" value="<?php echo $rows['title']; ?>">
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <?php echo $rows['topic_name']; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <?php echo $rows['topic_description']; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <input name="date[]" type="date" id="date" value="<?php echo $rows['event_date']; ?>">
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <input name="speaker[]" type="text" id="speaker" value="<?php echo $rows['speaker_name']; ?>">
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <input name="building[]" type="text" id="building" value="<?php echo $rows['building_name']; ?>">
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <input name="room[]" type="text" id="room" value="<?php echo $rows['room_name']; ?>">
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <?php
                        }
                    ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="8" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Update" value="UPDATE"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

#### results.php

the script that the `index.php` script is going to

```
    <?php
    require_once('dbconnect.php');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM event_list";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        $id = $_POST['event_id']; <!-- variable -->
        $title2 = $_POST['title'];
        $date2 = $_POST['date'];
        $speaker2 = $_POST['speaker'];
        $building2 = $_POST['building'];
        $room2 = $_POST['room'];

        for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
            echo "Title: ".$title2[$i]."<br>";
            $sql="UPDATE events SET title=$title2[$i], event_date='$date2[$i]', speaker_name='$speaker2[$i]', 
            building_name='$building2[$i]', room_name='$room2[$i]' 
            WHERE event_id='$id[$i]'"; <!-- error here -->
            $result1=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        }

    }
    ?>

        <table width="auto" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
            <form name="form1" method="post" action="index.php">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table width="auto" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center"><strong>Event ID</strong></td>
                                <td align="center"><strong>Title</strong></td>
                                <td align="center"><strong>Topic</strong></td>
                                <td align="center"><strong>Description</strong></td>
                                <td align="center"><strong>Event Date</strong></td>
                                <td align="center"><strong>Speaker</strong></td>
                                <td align="center"><strong>Building</strong></td>
                                <td align="center"><strong>Room</strong></td>
                            </tr>

                            <?php                    
                                while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                            ?>

                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <?php echo $rows['event_id'];?>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <?php echo $rows['title']; ?>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <?php echo $rows['topic_name']; ?>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <?php echo $rows['topic_description']; ?>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <?php echo $rows['event_date']; ?>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <?php echo $rows['speaker_name']; ?>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <?php echo $rows['building_name']; ?>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <?php echo $rows['room_name']; ?>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <?php
                                }
                            ?>

                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="8" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Return" value="Return"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </form>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run the `index.php` script, **without** putting an `if(isset())` around the `$id` variable in `results.php`, it tells me that it is an `Undefined Index`.  However, when I **DO** put the `if(isset())` aroung it, it tells me that within my `Update` SQL statement, the `id` that's in the `WHERE` clause is an `Undefined Variable`.

Like I said earlier, I'm still very new to PHP and I could really use some assistance.  I've looked on here (Stack) and found a "thread" about `Undefined Index/Variable/Offset` but it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: this is open to sql injection; use a prepared statement

Comment: HTML side note: `<form>` cannot be made child of `<table>`.

Comment: what is the exact error and on which line? you say undefined index then undefined variable. You also say that you saw the possible duplicate and state *"but it doesn't make sense to me."* but I fail to see what you did to fix this. This question stands to get closed with and possibly another/others,

Comment: `$id = $_POST['event_id']; <!-- variable -->` is that HTML comment method actually part of the code here? and use `mysqli_error($conn)` on the query then tell us what it shows.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like `event_id` is not sent up when you submit the form. If you output a hidden field specifying the `event_id` in your form you can access it via `$_POST` when the form is submitted:

`<input name="event_id" type="hidden" id="event_id" value="<?php echo $rows['event_id']; ?>">`

Make sure this line exists somewhere inside the form and it will be accessible in results.php via `$_POST['event_id']`.

Comment: Agreed, *but* you realize that that leaves them open to an sql injection. What would "you" do for that, so that their database won't get hacked?

Comment: If I was performing a QA or security audit there are a litany of issues to be resolved: parameterized queries, validation, decoupling of server and view logic, etc. But the context of the issue is a purely development environment, we don't even know if "production" would even be publicly accessible and at any risk of an outside attack.